# tronWeb.transactionBuilder.estimateEnergy cannot set properties of null

Tags: typescript, nestjs, tron, tronweb

i have nestjs typescript Apps in which connecting with tronweb and try to calculate estimated Gas.

```
const estimatedEnergy = await tronWeb.transactionBuilder.estimateEnergy(
    USDTContractAddress,
    'balanceOf(address)',
    null,
    abi,
    address,
);
```

this is my function but this error was returned:

```
    [Nest] 26120  - 26/03/2024, 4:23:09 pm   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot set properties of null (setting 'estimateEnergy')
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'estimateEnergy')
    at e.value (C:\app\node_modules\tronweb\dist\webpack:\tronweb\src\lib\transactionBuilder.js:1277:19)
    enter code here
    at Object.getEstimateGasFee (C:\app\src\tronweb\index.ts:108:62)
    at estimateGasFee (C:\app\src\controller.ts:48:41)
    at C:\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at C:\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at C:\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

how do i overcome this issues?
i've make sure the versions also the latest